# Should you re-ask a question if it's been asked but the answer hasn't worked for you?

Tags: discussion, support

There's this question:

[IIS does not list a website that matches the launch url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10716956/iis-does-not-list-a-website-that-matches-the-launch-url)

and then there's essentially the same question asked mentioning that the new questioner has tried the solutions mentioned in the previous question without actually referencing the previous question.

[IIS does not list a web site that matches the launched URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230439/iis-does-not-list-a-web-site-that-matches-the-launched-url)

Does this need to be flagged as a duplicate question?

Also, I've been in this situation before. What is the recommended approach to revive the question stating:

- I'm facing the same issue
- The answers in the previous question didn't work for me and
- I don't currently have a solution (because if I did, I'd post this as an alternate answer to the original question)

Comment: Bounty is what you are looking for. Should be enough similar questions on meta already on this topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have a question that has already been asked, but the solutions don't work for you, it's OK to ask the question. But, you should:

- Link to the existing question(s); and
- Explain *why* the solutions presented in that question don't work for you

This way you are showing you have research the problem and tried the existing solutions. This will prevent people dupe hammering immediately and/or providing answers that already exist, hopefully quickly getting to new answers that help.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Steve's answer; if you explain why a similar question didn't work for you, it should be fine.

With that said, a few *other* possibilities are to add a bounty to the original question, comment on the question/answers asking for additional details, edit the question to "bump" it for recent activity, or edit to make it easier to find (e.g. improve the tags, edit the title/phrasing to make it easier to find in searches, etc.)